# How to remove extra page in Lyx

Tags: page-breaking

I am working in Lyx and compiling a book layout. After each chapter an extra blank page appears. How can that extra page be removed?

```
\batchmode
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{C:/Users/Anuja/Documents//}}
\makeatother
\documentclass[english,openany]{book}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subscript}
\doublespacing

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter


\title{\textbf{\huge{}Title}}

\maketitle

\chapter*{}


\chapter*{Acknowledgements}


\chapter*{Publications}


\chapter*{List of Figures}


\chapter*{List of Tables}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In `book` chapters always start on a right hand page, so you can get empty pages at end of chapters. This is intended, but if you prefer this not to happen, add `openany` to the  customdocument class options in Document --> Settings --> Document class.

Comment: Where is this option? I am not able to get it.

Comment: Document --> Settings --> Document class. Under the heading *Class options* there is a text field called *Custom*. Type `openany` there.

Comment: Thanks a lot  the problem is solved. An extra page appears after the title as well. How can that be removed?

Comment: No idea, don't think there should be one by default, so we need more information: try making a minimal working example, see http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an empty chapter heading, i.e. the line saying `\chapter*{}`, the empty page actually contains that. Delete that one and you should be fine.